# session cookie not being sent when front-end is run on a server

Tags: reactjs, azure, asp.net-web-api, session-cookies, asp.net-authorization

I am working on a project in which we decided to separate our code base into two separate repositories (a react front-end and .net web API back-end). We have not had any problems running the back-end on a server and the front-end locally, but when it came time to move the front-end project to a server we started running into issues.

The back-end project uses .NETs authentication in order to manage sessions. We are able to make anonymous API calls to the back-end from the front-end. However, any of the calls that require authorization are failing with a 404 not found. I think this is because the session cookie is not being sent with the API requests although I could be wrong.

We are using fetch to make the API calls from the front-end, here is an example of what the call bodies look like:

```
 {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      },
      credentials: 'include',
    }
```

The back-end .NET project is set up to allow cors from anywhere but I am not sure if I need to make additional changes to the server or if I should try to move the front end to the same server.

**The front-end is using Firebase hosting**

**The back-end is using Azure**

I will update the post with any additional information needed!

I am not super familiar with hosting or servers so any help would be appreciated in solving the issue!

Comment: You say Local to Server is working fine. So session cookies are being sent with API. Add log trace for 404 and also check if you have whitelisted localhost URL related to CORS. Also check in azure if you need to open any specific PORT to allow call.

Comment: May be problem in your cookie domain or path???

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be an issue with CORS. The firebase server provided 2 urls that needed to be whitelisted on the azure server when we were previously only whitelisting 1.

**mywebsite.web.app**
and
**mywebsite.firebaseapp.com**

both needed to be listed